# Cyclic IObservable Chain in Reactive .NET

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming, dataflow

I'm looking for the best way to implement cyclic IObservable chains.

For example:

```
IObservable<B> Foo(IObservable<A> fizz)
{
    //stuff
}

IObservable<A> Bar(IObservable<A> fizz, IObservable<B> buzz)
{
    //stuff
}
```

My implementation:

```
var fizzes = new BehaviorSubject<A>();
var buzzes = Foo(fizzes);
Bar(fizzes, buzzes).Subscribe(f => fizzes.OnNext(f));
```

Is there a better way to do this? Feels dirty using Subject, and generally less-than-elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
Bar(fizzes, buzzes).Subscribe(f => fizzes.OnNext(f));
```

can be made simpler and changed to

```
Bar(fizzes, buzzes).Subscribe(fizzes);
```

as the `Subscribe` method takes an `IObserver`, the lambda methods that are normally used are just shortcuts for this.

As such, `fizzes` is being used as an `IObserver` and an `IObservable`, which is the definition of a `Subject`. If this is the behavior that you want, then a `Subject` is probably the way to go.